# How do I use string classnames in Lit's css

Tags: javascript, css, lit

I want to store classnames in JS consts like this:

```
const someClassName = "menu-item";
const componentCss = css`
  .${someClassName} {
    background: red;
  }
`;
```

And then use them in html templates like this:

```
const componentRender = html`
  <some-element class="${someClassName}"><some-element>
`;
```

The problem is: Lit doesn't allow strings in the `css` function, I know I can wrap every single class in `unsafeCSS` every time I use it in `css`, but is there a better way  to do this?

Comment: Lit's CSS literal isn't really meant for styles whose definition is changed using JavaScript, is there any reason why you want to do this? There might be a better approach to achieve your use case using CSS variables, shadow parts, or another technique

Comment: Classnames, which are stored in JS consts are easier to refactor, to search for them and are generally more strict than just the regular string ones. So that's why I'm trying to find an elegant way to use them

Comment: You can also structure the classes any way you want with objects, like this:
```
linkGroup: {
  header: "sidebar-link-group-header",
  headerLabel: "sidebar-link-group-header-label",
  chevron: "sidebar-link-group-header-chevron",
  collapsed: "sidebar-link-group-collapsed",
  links: "sidebar-link-group-links",
  toString: () => "sidebar-link-group",
},
```

Comment: When using shadow DOM, you arguably don't really need to have complicated class names or sometimes even use classes at all unless you have a lot of elements inside your component